# IDA Xrefs from - how to?

Tags: ida, tools, ida-plugin

I want to generate all xrefs from function just to check what api it uses in its call-tree. I know I can generate call tree graph by right clicking on function name and "Xrefs from", but I would like to have this functions listed just as text or something like that, so I could read it easily.

Reading it from WinGraph is pretty hard, and I have trouble with this nasty colors..
I mean, how is it readable? It is really hard to read white text on cyan background. And I dont see any way to configure it. My eyes just cant stand looking at it.

So how can I get this xrefs in some friendly format? I am sure it is possible.. 
I am using IDA 6.1

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [MyNav](https://code.google.com/p/mynav/) plugin will show you calls from a function recursively, as shown below:
[image]

Answer (score 3):

I didn't check it, use carefully, beware the errors in this code, good luck

```
import idautils
import idc
import idaapi

def handle_function(func_start):
    for h in idautils.FuncItems(func_start):
        for r in idautils.XrefsFrom(h, 0):
            if r.type == fl_CF or r.type == fl_CN:
                print hex(h), "--calls-->", hex(r.to)

handle_function(address_of_your_function)
```

Answer (score 1):

View | Open subviews | Function calls.

[image: IDA Function calls view]

Comment: Thanks for this, but what I really want is call-tree like this http://i.imgur.com/rQvraS8.png . (which includes more than 0 level calls) I think I have to write script like user w s proposed me, but edit it so its search deeper..