# Access a XREFs with frida

Tags: ida, disassemblers, ios, javascript, frida

I have a string which has a XREF to a func. This func changes of address at every updates of the app I am working on. So this string is the only "stable" point I can rely on to access to func.

```
                     aOpensslCertVer:
00000000047fef1d         db         "openssl cert verify error: ", 0            ; DATA XREF=sub_342df4+412
```

So I'd like to obtain the XREF pointer with a Frida script, how can I do that ? Is it even possible to do ?

I found out [here](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/4276/ida-xrefs-from-how-to) that it seems you can do it with IDA in python, but I use something else than IDA, and I'd like to do it dynamically from Frida JS.

How can I do it ? Is it even possible to do ? Thanks !

Comment: For resolving XREF you first have to analyze the whole binary, so this is more a job for IDA Pro or Ghidra. You can first analyze the binary offline in IDA/Ghidra, extract the xref and send this data to Frida for a dynamic analysis (e.g. write the value into a Frida script before loading it).

Comment: try if you can set a hardware breakpoint and catch read access  check this issue and proposal  https://github.com/frida/frida/issues/2055

Comment: Another possibility would be to hook the function and then each time generate the stack trace in frida https://codeshare.frida.re/@razaina/get-a-stack-trace-in-your-hook/ That way you would at least some of the xref functions (depending on whyt code parts are executed at run-time).